# failed to shutdown tomcat after adding javaagent : FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Tags: tomcat, prometheus

I used promutheus to monitor tomcat, and the result was feasible. but i failed to shutdown tomcat. Here are some key steps and info:

1，tomcat catalina.bat file path:

```
`E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\bin`
```

2, jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.2.jar file path:

```
`F:/work-Grafana/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.2.jar`
```

3, modify catalina.bat file：

`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %JSSE_OPTS% -javaagent:F:/work-Grafana/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.17.2.jar=2023:F:/work-Grafana/prometheus-2.42.0.windows-amd64/jmx-exporter.yaml"`

4, modify prometheus.yml file：

- job_name: "tomcat"
  static_configs:
  - targets: ["127.0.0.1:2023"]

5，run tomcat, run prometheus, everything is OK.

```
`E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\bin>startup.bat
 Using CATALINA_BASE:   "E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71"
 Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71"
 Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\temp"
 Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201"
 Using CLASSPATH:       "E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\work-    tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
  Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""`
```

6, shutdown tomcat, failed.
`    E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\bin>shutdown.bat

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201"
Using CLASSPATH:       "E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\bin\bootstrap.jar;E:\work-tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.71\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:100)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
    at     sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:130)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.shaded.io.prometheus.client.exporter.HTTPServer.<init>(HTTPServer.java:396)
    at io.prometheus.jmx.JavaAgent.premain(JavaAgent.java:31)
    ... 6 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed`
```

i want to solve this problem:
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed`

Answer (score 0):

Use `CATALINA_OPTS` to set the javaagent parameters. It allows specification of additional options for the Java command that starts Tomcat.
`JAVA_OPTS` is intended for options that are used both to start and to stop Tomcat as well as for other commands.
See https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/main/bin/catalina.sh#L65